# Dynamically object record Save into database using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**Respected Sir/Ma'am**

```
    I have record in below format and want to save this into 
    database,the property of this particular object is not similar often, It's changeable,
    Sometime it could be more and sometime it could be less
```

**the property of this object is changeable,Sometime it could be
more and sometime it could be less**

```
{
    "name":"nabnit jha",
    "email":"028nabnit@gmail.com",
    "password":"123456",
    "c_password":"123456",
    "imgUrl":"sonujha.jpg"
}
```

**Simply i will do this if object property is not dynamic**

```
    public function insert($data, $modelName)
    {
        $modelName->name = $data->name;
        $modelName->email = $data->email;
        $modelName->password = $data->password;
        $modelName->img_url = $data->imgUrl;
        $modelName->save();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Record Inserted Successfully"
        ]);
    }
```

**what I DO In dynamic case, I use this but not work please help me**

```
 public function insert($data, $modelName)
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $modelName->$key = $value;
        }

        $modelName->save();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Record Inserted Successfully"
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: You should store your data in json format  in single column with the use of `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`

Answer (score 0):

data must be array

```
public function insert($data, $modelName)
{
    $modelName->fill($data)->save(); // or use forceFill()

    return response()->json([
        'message' => "Record Inserted Successfully"
    ]);
}
```

Comment: How I convert above object to Array, Plz help me

{
    "name":"nabnit jha",
    "email":"028nabnit@gmail.com",
    "password":"123456",
    "c_password":"123456",
    "imgUrl":"sonujha.jpg"
}

Answer (score 0):

If someone has same issue then take **$data = $request->input()** and use foreach loop

### **For more detail follow bellow step**

**Step 1**

```
class SignUp extends Controller
{
    //
    protected $users;
    public function __construct(Crud $crud)
    {
        $this->users = $crud;
        $this->Model = new RegisterSignUp;
    }

    public function singleUpload(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData =  Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required',
                'c_password' => 'required|same:password'
            ]
        );

        if ($validatedData->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "Validation Error"
            ]);
        }
        $model_name = $this->getModel();
        $result =  $this->users->insert($request->input(), $model_name);
        return $result;

        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Record Inserted Successfully"
        ]);
    }

    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->Model;
    }
}
```

**Step 2**

```
 public function insert($data, $modelName)
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != 'c_password') {
                $modelName->$key = $value;
            }
        }
        $modelName->save();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Record Inserted Successfully"
        ]);
    }
```